# JavaScript Function Call With OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a simple function that works when it is hard coded, but when I try to pass a second parameter into it, it doesn't work. I am calling the function with the `onclick` and using the `id => thumbnail` to get the value. Any suggestions?

**Hard Coded Example (Works)**

```
<script>
  function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
     document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
     $('.thumbnail').val("");
  }
</script>

<div id="thumbnail_div" class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelex($model,'thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textfield($model,'thumbnail', array(placeholder => "No file chosen", readonly => true, 'class' => 'thumbnail')); ?><br>
    <?php echo $form->filefield($model,'thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'thumbnail'); ?>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick = "clearFileInputField('thumbnail_div')" href="javascript:noAction();"> Remove Thumbnail
</div>
```

**Parameters Passed (Not Working)**

```
 <script>
   function clearFileInputField(tagId, div) {
      document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
      $('.div').val("");
    }
    </script>

    <div id="thumbnail_div" class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelex($model,'thumbnail'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textfield($model,'thumbnail', array(placeholder => "No file chosen", readonly => true, 'id' => 'thumbnail')); ?><br>
        <?php echo $form->filefield($model,'thumbnail'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'thumbnail'); ?>

        <input type="checkbox" onclick = "clearFileInputField('thumbnail_div', 'thumbnail')" href="javascript:noAction();"> Remove Thumbnail
    </div>
```

Comment: Not working meaning?

Comment: The hard coded example will clear the correct data. Whereas, the code that passes Parameters doesn't not clear the data.

Comment: Can you check the console logs for errors?....Works for me..Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ucj3mpdv/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. In your code, the paramenter div is converted to string. Instead of that, try the code given below,

```
<script>
       function clearFileInputField(tagId, div) {
                document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = 
                              document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
                    $('.'+div).val("");        
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.div').val("");
  ^^^^^^
```

That's a string, not a variable. You're trying to find elements that have `class="div"`.

You need to concatenate the variable with a string containing the dot.:

```
$('.' + div).val("");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.div').val("");
```

That part is close but not going to work as you might have intended. You instead should have it one of two ways,

```
$('.'+div).val("");
```

or,

```
$(div).val("");
```

With option 1, you are using a string for the period and concatenating it with the value of the variable *div*

With option 2, you will need to change the passed parameter to include a period before it.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily get rid of your inline handler and just create a simple event handler.

```js
jQuery(function(){
  // Bind a handler to any button with the class remove_thumbnail
  $('.remove_thumbnail').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {     
      $(this)
        // go up to parent row
        .parents('.row')
        // find the thumbnail
        .find('.thumbnail')
        .val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnail_div" class="row">
  <input type="text" class="thumbnail" value="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" class="remove_thumbnail"> Remove Thumbnail
</div>
```

The advantages here are that you separate content and behavior and do not introduce functions into the global scope.

Answer (score -2):

try this (with script placed underneath the markup):

```
<div id="thumbnail_div" class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelex($model,'thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textfield($model,'thumbnail', array(placeholder => "No file chosen", readonly => true, 'id' => 'thumbnail')); ?><br>
    <?php echo $form->filefield($model,'thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'thumbnail'); ?>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick = "clearFileInputField('thumbnail_div', 'thumbnail')" href="javascript:noAction();"> Remove Thumbnail
</div>

 <script>
        function clearFileInputField(tagId, div) {
            document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
            $('.'+div).val("");

        }
</script>
```